# Z-axis label not Printed Properly in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter, visualization

I have come across an annoying problem while doing my homework. I am trying to print a 3-D plot and the Z-axis label is not printed properly. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

```
## Plotting data points with cluster colors
ax.scatter(x[:, 1], x[:, 2], x[:, 0], s=50, c=labels.astype(float))

## Plotting cluster centers 
markers = ['o', 'v', '^', '<', '>']
cluster_colors = {i: f'C{i}' for i in range(clusterNum)}
for i in range(clusterNum):
    cluster_mask = labels == i
    ax.scatter(k_means.cluster_centers_[i, 1],
           k_means.cluster_centers_[i, 2],
           k_means.cluster_centers_[i, 0],
           s=200, marker=markers[i],
           c=cluster_colors[i],
           edgecolors='k',
           alpha=0.5)

ax.scatter(x[cluster_mask, 1], 
           x[cluster_mask, 2], 
           x[cluster_mask, 0], 
           s=50, c=cluster_colors[i], 
           marker='o', 
           edgecolors='k', 
           alpha=0.5)

ax.set_xlabel('Age', fontsize=12)
ax.set_ylabel('Income', fontsize=12)
ax.set_zlabel('Gender (0 = Female, 1 = Male)', fontsize=12)
plt.title('K-Means Clusters (3D): Age|Income|Gender')

## Create badass legend entries
legend_entries = [plt.scatter([], [], s=50, c=cluster_colors[i], 
                          marker=markers[i], edgecolors='k', 
                          label='Cluster {}'.format(i))
                          for i in range(clusterNum)]

## Again, a legend without a title, is a fokin spaghetti without 
## little meat balls. :)
plt.legend(handles=legend_entries, scatterpoints=1,
       fontsize=10, title='Cluster Centers')

plt.show()`
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nV36V.png)

Expected a full print of the label.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.set_box_aspect.html) is useful for zooming out a bit in order to show the z label:

`ax.set_box_aspect(aspect=None, zoom=0.8)`